# How to make parentheses usable as macro delimiters when the macro is passed as a point in RPN notation?

Tags: macros, pstricks

How to make `(` and `)` usable as macro delimiters when the macro is passed as a point in RPN notation?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\def\f#1{#1 2 exp 1 sub}
\def\g[#1]{#1 2 exp 1 sub}
\def\h(#1){#1 2 exp 1 sub}
\def\i<#1>{#1 2 exp 1 sub}
\def\j|#1|{#1 2 exp 1 sub}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](-4,-2)(4,4)
    \psplot{-2}{2}{\f x}
    \psdots(!0 \f{0})
    \psdots(!-2 \g[-2])
%   \psdots(!2 \h(2))% <== cannot be compiled!
    \psdots(!1.25 \i<1.25>)
    \psdots(!1.5 \j|1.5|)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In `\psdots(!2 \h(2))` the *first* `)` is the delimiter for the argument to `\psdots`. You can use `\edef\temp{\noexpand\psdots(!2 \h(2))}\temp`, but of course a different delimiter is better.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: #1 doesn't need a \space

Answer (score 8, accepted):

that is the default problem with TeX and how it reads tokens. It looks for the first ( and the first ), the reason why you cannot use that kind of notation. It is a similiar problem as the well known `[...[...]]`. However, you can use the algebraic notation:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\def\f#1{#1 2 exp 1 sub}
\def\g[#1]{#1 2 exp 1 sub}
\def\h(#1){#1^2-1}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](-4,-2)(4,4)
\psplot{-2}{2}{\f x}
\psdots(!0 \f{0})(!-2 \g[-2])(*2 {\h(x)})(*1 {x^2-1})
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

as an alternative you can use

```
\def\h{dup 2 exp 1 sub}
\psdot(!2 \h)
```

it makes no sense to use an argument for h which is already present on top of the stack. Same for `\g`. The other way roung is (which also works):

```
\def\h(#1){#1 dup 2 exp 1 sub}
\psdot(!{\h(2)})
```

However, if one wants the double parentheses then it can be solved with

```
\psdot(!2 {\h(2)}/Y ED Y)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit about `/Y ED Y`?

Comment: `{..} /Y ED` is a definition like `/Y {...} def` where `ED` is a short name for `exch def`. With `{\h(2)}/Y ED Y` the value of `\h(2)` is saved as `Y` which is then called.

Answer (score 2):

As Herbert notes, `\psdots` takes the first right parenthesis as a delimiter, not the second.  This common TeX problem is solved in the `xparse` package.  Here I save the definition of `\psdots` and redefine it with `xparse` to take a "required" argument "`r`" delimited by `(` and `)`.  Those delimiters will be paired, so `#1` is `!2 \h(2)` as wanted.  I then feed this `#1` to the saved `\psdots` within parentheses: the extra set of braces around `#1` ensure that the correct argument is used.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\usepackage{xparse}
\let\savedpsdots\psdots
\RenewDocumentCommand {\psdots} {r()} {\savedpsdots({#1})}

\def\f#1{#1 2 exp 1 sub}
\def\g[#1]{#1 2 exp 1 sub}
\def\h(#1){#1 2 exp 1 sub}
\def\i<#1>{#1 2 exp 1 sub}
\def\j|#1|{#1 2 exp 1 sub}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=bottom](-4,-2)(4,4)
    \psplot{-2}{2}{\f x}
    \psdots(!0 \f{0})
    \psdots(!-2 \g[-2])
    \psdots(!2 \h(2))% <== could be compiled!
    \psdots(!1.25 \i<1.25>)
    \psdots(!1.5 \j|1.5|)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

A more general solution would be to redefine `\pst@object` which seems to underlie a few `pst-plot` commands.

Comment: PSTricks can be used with TeX and LaTeX, but xparse only for LaTeX, right? And it is easier to solve it on PS level: `\psdot(!2 {\h(2)}/Y ED Y)`

Comment: @Herbert You're right, although it wouldn't be too hard to make `xparse` and `expl3` available to TeX if people ask for it.  The simplest solution if we're allowed to change the OP's input is `\psdots({...})`, since TeX will discard those braces when taking a delimited argument.

Comment: sure, but then we need an additional expanding which is not easy to realize. The argument can have several optional parameters.

Comment: @Herbert: I don't understand your comment: `\pst@@getcoors` is defined with `\def\pst@@getcoors(#1){...}`.  When TeX sees `\pst@@getcoors({...})`, it feeds the argument `...` (without surrounding braces) to `\pst@@getcoors`, which is precisely what the OP wants, isn't it?

Comment: yes when we have not activated special coordinates with an active ! * | ; >. That is the default case which is not used in the above example.

Comment: @Herbert: ok, I trust your knowledge of `pstricks` :).